# How do I interpret SaLib output?

Tags: python, optimization

I am running SaLib on a custom function and have received the following output:

```
{'S1': array([0.12899883, 0.76176135]),
 'S1_conf': array([0.28196636, 0.71331346]),
 'S2': array([[nan, -0.05734368],[nan,nan]]),
 'S2_conf': array([[nan, 0.37239091],[nan,nan]]),
 'ST': array([0.0908465 , 0.61461588]),
 'ST_conf': array([0.15045759, 0.45453896])}
```

How do I go about interpreting the S1 and ST outputs specifically?

I was under the impression that S1 or ST should all add up 1 but clearly thats not happening in my case.

Am I to assume that 9% and 61.4% of my output variance is determined by input1 and input2? And the remaining variance by other inputs not defined in my problem?

Answer (score 1):

The first-order index, S1, accounts for the variance from that variable alone (no interactions with other variables). The total-order index, ST, accounts for the variance from the input and the interactions of the given input with the others. Generally, the sum of of S1 values should be less than 1 and the sum of ST values should be greater than 1. (This [post](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_it_ever_possible_to_have_the_sum_of_first-order_Sobol_indices_greater_than_one) could be helpful on interpretation.)

In your example, 9% of the variance would be attributable to input1 alone and the input1-input2 interaction. Similarly, 61% of the variance is attributable to input2 alone and the input1-input2 interaction. **The S1_conf and ST_conf show that there is high uncertainty on the estimates of the indices.** It would be difficult to report an index with such large uncertainty.

To obtain more reliable estimates the sample sizes should be increased, probably by a factor of 10 or more. Without more information on the type of model you are using it is difficult to determine what could cause these results besides sampling uncertainty.

Comment: Thank you! When you say generally the sum of S1 values is less than 1 - what is the remaining variance comprised of? In my example input1 and input2 are the only variables, so I would have expected the combined S1 across both those would be 1.

Comment: There is a term in the Sobol decomposition for the interaction of input1 and input2. This would be the second-order index, which is reported as S2.